# Mac won't show screen

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Since the beginning of today, the time now being midday, I've been having issues with my MacBook Pro. Even when I closed everything it refuses to work. Basically when I close the lid, everything is fine but when I open it the screen just doesn't turn on. The sleep light remains at a single level of light, rather than brightening and dimming over the course of several seconds. If I hold the power button down sometimes it will bring the screen back after what looks like a progress bar and sometimes it will reboot the machine.

If anyone can help me, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Your Mac has a powerfull self monitoring, in the Utilities, Console it logs all events. Look at it for errors, or post it here so we can see what is going on. Since it can be very long log, only post the section based on the time stamp when you close and open the lid, about 20 lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another device you could try a remote connection. Personally I would be tempted to SSH into the Macbook and see what processes are at play.

This will of course only work if you have 'remote login' enabled on your Mac.

> System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login

From an iPhone you could then install an SSH client (search: ssh) from the App store and try connecting in.

After login you could try

```
$ ps -A |more
```

to list all processes currently running a page a time (space to advance)
or

```
$ top
```

this will give you a list of processes (q to quit)

Comment: Maktann here. I'll give that a shot when I get home.

Comment: By all means post back your findings. I might be able to help further if this is still an issue for you.